# Site altered when retrieved via mobile internet connection

Tags: http, http-headers

Today I found out that my site returns different responses using different connections. 
Using my computer with a wired internet connection my site is behaving as it should and returns the latest changes, but using a mobile phone returns my site as it was two years ago.

Response headers using a wired internet connection:

```
Cache-Control → no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection → Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding → gzip
Content-Length → 8533
Content-Type → text/html
Date → Mon, 28 Dec 2015 09:44:57 GMT
Expires → Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive → timeout=5, max=100
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary → Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By → PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
```

Response headers by sharing the internet connection from my phone. Same browser and same URL as before. For some reason it will return an old page, but I expect it to return the latest one.

```
Accept-Ranges → bytes
Age → 0
Cache-Control → no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Encoding → gzip
Content-Length → 3544
Content-Type → text/html
Date → Mon, 28 Dec 2015 09:34:41 GMT
Expires → Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary → Accept-Encoding
Via → 1.1 varnish
X-Cache-Hit → MISS
X-Varnish → 1701875350
```

I don't know how to start debug this. Can't think of any reason why it would return different responses depending on different connections.

**Update:**
Problem was my DNS settings. The AAAA record was pointing to the wrong server. 
So the issue appeared when using my mobile IPv6 connection.
I leave the correct answer as it is since it wasn't a bad answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile ISPs have the (bad) habit of transparently filtering what you request using unencrypted connections. Most of the time, it's well-intentioned (they compress pictures to save transfer volume/be faster), but it's known to break things. I don't know if there are mobile ISPs that inject their own advertisements, but that business model existed for fixed subscriber lines for quite some times, so that's certainly possible.

If you can, ask your Mobile ISP to stop doing that. Other than that, there's nothing you can do, aside from doing the right thing: Enforce SSL usage: Forward everyone that requests `http://yoursite/yourpath` to `http`**`s`**://yoursite/yourpath`, and configure your web server to serve things via HTTPS. That way, no provider can play a man in the middle attack on your service.

Comment: Great! Contacted my mobile ISP and asked them to remove my website from their cache and now it works great :)